# Integrated authentication failed on JDBC connection to SQLEXPRESS with Windows authentication

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-server-2012, connection-string, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am seeking help with the subject error I received when trying to connect to a 2012 SSMS Express database through Oracle Developer Data Modeler.

Connection settings in Oracle are:

> JDBC URL:  jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos
>   Driver class:  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

I have put sqljdbc_auth.dll in the following directories with no success:

- C:\Oracle Data Modeler\datamodeler\datamodeler\bin
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin (64-bit put here)
- C:\Windows\System32

Can anyone offer any guidance?  All files are on my local laptop, which is 64-bit processor running Windows 7 32-bit.

The same error resulted when adding the additional property of serverName.

Thank you for any ideas.